# href does not work on anchor

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp, anchor

I have the following piece of javascript. It is using Ajax to get a quote from an API. The quote is presented at the quote div, but the href is not being refreshed at the twitterAnchor.

```js
    jQuery('#button').on('click', function(){
            
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&  filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=mycallback",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(json){
            document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = json[0].content;
            document.getElementById('twitterAnchor').href =  "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + json[0].content;    
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<!-- Here is the anchor. -->

      <div id="tweet">
          <a id ="twitterAnchor" href="" class="twitter-share-button" target="_blank" >Tweet</a>  
      </div>
```

When I click the twitterAnchor the page is refreshed. The console shows me nothing, does anybody have a hint of what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one day trying to find the error... that's the solution:

```
jQuery('#button').on('click', function(){

    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=mycallback",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(json){
        document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = json[0].content; 
        }
    });
});

jQuery('#twitterAnchor').on('click', function () {
    jQuery(this).attr("href","https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML);
});
```

The problem is: if you try to change the href inside the ajax connection, it does not work. I really don't know why, and I would be really glad to know.

Answer (score 0):

Do not assign a new value to href, instead use jQuery `attr` method.

```
$('#twitterAnchor').attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + json[0].content);
```

Comment: Yes buddy, I'm using it, but outside of my ajax connection. It doesn't work inside. My answer is below.

Comment: You aren't using it in your original answer is what I'm saying.